# How do I write the correct condition for my htaccess file?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, pagination

Some code caused pagination on post pages in wordpress. Consequently I now have hundreds of dynamic pages that Google indexed. I have removed the code, and also stopped G from indexing them but they still exist in the G database. I want anything in below format to give a 410 error to Google which I believe will solve the issue.

My permalink structure is www.domain.com/post-name

For some reason the erroneous code linked up each post to

www.domain.com/post-name/page/1

www.domain.com/post-name/page/2

and so on for hundreds of posts.

Since my posts are never paginated, I basically want to have the condition that will cause Google to get a 410 error for any

www.domain.com/post-name/page/*

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/page/(.*)$ [L,R=410]
```

did not work

I am not a programmer so if you could ELI5 with the code then it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /page/\d+$ - [NC,L,R=410]
```

Comment: Thanks Croises, but my pagination is domain.com/page/2 and so on. wouldnt this code mean any URL with page in it become a 410? I wouldnt want this to impact my actual pagination. only when its domain.com/article-name/page/2 etc needs to 410.

Comment: I add a number after. But you have to explain to the server how to recognize "article-name"...